# How to upload project into Amazon ECS using cli

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I am learning how to automate my project delivery.
I am able to create cluster and but I am stuck on the step where I have to upload files to the EC2 instance.

Right now I am running these commands

```
ecs-cli up --keypair my_keypair --capability-iam --size 1 --instance-type t2.micro --force
```

This creates the cluster.
Then I create docker container for php and nginx.

```
ecs-cli compose up
```

This creates containers but without any files.

NOW if I **manually login into to EC2** instance using SSH and create **phpinfo.php** file then I can view it in browser telling me that everything is setup correct. But it is the manual step. How can i push my project files automatically ?

May be I don't understand how this works and am going in wrong direction.
All the tutorials that i saw used readymade wordpress image. I am not deploying wordpress image. I want to deploy phpinfo.php (for example).

Thanks

```
version: '2'

services:
  nginx:
      image: tutum/nginx
      cpu_shares: 50
      mem_limit: 134217728
      ports:
          - "80:80"
      links:
          - phpfpm
      volumes:
          - /home/ec2-user/nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/sites-available/
          - /home/ec2-user/nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
          - /home/ec2-user/public:/var/www/html
  phpfpm:
      image: php-nginx-fpm:7.0.19-37
      cpu_shares: 50
      mem_limit: 134217728
      ports:
          - "9000:9000"
          - "3306:3306"
      volumes:
          - /home/ec2-user/public:/var/www/html
```

Comment: Why down vote? I am facing an issue and wanted help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using ECS - the Elastic Container Service - you need to Dockerize your application first, and upload the resulting Docker image to [Amazon ECR](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide): the Elastic Container Registry.

To do this you need to go into EC2 Container Service -> Registry and create a repository for your container. You then configure

In your source code you need to have a Dockerfile that builds your container: starting from a base image then `ADD`ing your source code to the container.

Once you have that, you either need to have your build server build and push the docker container, or just do it manually from your machine.

You set your [ECS service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_services.html?shortFooter=true) to use the docker image from ECR, and when you do a docker push to the ECR, you "update" the task definition so it grabs the latest version of the docker container.

You can set up ECS and ECR either through the aws cli, as you started, via the web console itself (click click), or via some infrastructure provisioning tool like Cloudformation or Terraform. Whatever floats your needs that way...

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Your answer makes most sense. Thank you again. I will try to learn how to **Dockerize an application**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am stuck at a point where my app is in the *phpfpm* container but it is *not available* in the nginx container. My app was shipping in *phpfpm container* so it is ONLY VISIBLE in that container. How did you guys solve that?

Comment: Two choices, and I don’t know the best one for PHP or your app. You could just put the PHP stuff in the same container as the nginx, or use something like Docker Compose to kink the containers together.

Comment: I have posted the question here with more details. Please can you check. Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47202692/sharing-app-files-between-phpfpm-and-nginx-in-docker-containers

Comment: Just so you know, my app is only phpinfo.php (which is a single line file like hello world)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this by using S3 bucket.  Follow below steps:

1. Create a bucket in S3 and upload your code to S3 from your local folder either using console or following command

   aws s3 sync . s3://mybucket
2. Now create an EC2 role in AWS and add S3 Read permission.
3. Assign this role to your EC2 instance.  Now your EC2 has permission to download the code.
4. Whenever you want your code in EC2 you can download using below command (you can also include this command in your bootstrap script)

   aws s3 sync s3://mybucket .

The good part is S3 sync command will upload/download delta files only.  So if you modify only one file and execute above commands, only modified file will be uploaded to S3 and downloaded to EC2.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I would like to learn more on these steps. Is there any AWS tutorial or any other tutorial that you are aware of?

Comment: These links will help you.. 
 http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/upload-objects.html         https://optimalbi.com/blog/2016/07/12/aws-tips-and-tricks-moving-files-from-s3-to-ec2-instance/

Comment: If I login into EC2 and run this command `aws s3 sync s3://domain.com/ /home/ec2-user` i get command not found error. Should i run it in my development laptop ?

Comment: If you launched AMI instance it should have aws cli.  If not you can install awscli.  Refer this link  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-linux.html

Comment: YES ECS instances dont have aws. Have to manually install. In EC2 instances aws is installed but not docker. Figured out today :) Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

You could use scp. This uses ssh to copy the file over in a way thats much easier to automate.

```
scp file <sshtarget>:/path/to/file
```

If you're willing to change your deploy process, you could instead use a CloudFormation template.

[This page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/deploying.applications.html) describes how to deploy an ec2 instance with files already on it. (Look at the 'Files' section under step 2)

Comment: But is it the standard process? Is this how **DevOp expert** will deploy their project? I want to learn which is more important to me. I can easily write a complex shell script that can achieve everything but I need to know how professionals are doing it

Comment: Also not to forget, ip address of the EC2 instance can change. After all it is all stateless.

Comment: @Sallu Is it possible to containerize your application? Or would you be open to using CloudFormation instead?
At my job we use a combination of scripts in a build pipeline (like jenkins) and CloudFormation templates with dockerized containers.

Comment: what do you mean by containerise my application? do you mean make a container image with application? I am sorry I didnt understand. I am open to anything that helps me learn how devops are doing it.

Comment: @Sallu The cloud is still fairly new, and changing a lot. DevOps teams currently use lots of different processes based on which technologies they are working with and which specific use case they are targeting. Ive seen everything from Service Catalog docker instances to Lambda based solutions.

But, for deploying things to AWS its definitely worthwhile to familiarise yourself with CloudFormation templates. They are the default way you automate deployment to aws

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I saw that link. They are including index.php source code in the script. Can you include file name or directory name there and it includes files recursively or I can make zip of my project in Jenkins and use cloudfront to unzip and deploy?

Comment: Is there a way to put my application (php files) into a docker container image? When I do `compose up`, my application can be deployed also