# Sharing app files between phpfpm and nginx in docker containers

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I am trying to deploy simple phpinfo.php to ECS (Amazon EC2 Container Service).

I was told that if I **Dockerize** my app and push resulting image to Amazon ECR (Elastic Container Registry), EC2 can easily get app from there.

I did that and NOW I have hit another road block.

After deploying in EC2 container, **the problem** is that my app is in ONLY phpfpm container in folder /var/www/html/ but IT IS NOT VISIBLE IN my **nginx** container.

Due to this problem, nginx does not delivery my app.

Please note that app is not in the host device EC2, nor it is in nginx, it is only in php-fpm. How to solve this problem? Please advise. Thanks

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  nginx:
      image: 607167.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/nginx:1
      cpu_shares: 50
      mem_limit: 134217728
      ports:
          - "80:80"
      links:
          - phpfpm
  phpfpm:
      image: 60547.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/phpinfo:latest
      cpu_shares: 50
      mem_limit: 134217728
      ports:
          - "9000:9000"
          - "3306:3306"
```

I tried add this line to both containers in yml file but then my containers fail to load.

```
  volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Is it something that is working locally? On your machine, without any EC2 notion involved? To access the containers on *ECR* with the *aws cli* client, use `aws ecr get-login`

Comment: @arvymetal this is all working inside EC2 instance. 2 containers are inside EC2 instance

Comment: In fact I don't really get what's the relation between the `docker-compose.yml` file you're showing and *ECS*. *ECS* relies on task definitions instead...

Comment: Also, sorry for the confusion, but I don't get if your comment means that the 2 containers are working correctly inside the EC2 instance, or just that they are running inside of it... In which case I was advising you to reproduce the issue locally.

Comment: And a last comment: mounting a volume in a container overrides what's in the container at this location. Containers can communicate by sharing a volume whose content is on the host, or through sockets, but a container can't access the file system of another container... By the way, I also containerized a PHP server, and it's a pain. The better is to leave PHP-FPM and NGINX together. However I don't get why I see the port 3306 here... If the database is here, it should however be separated to another container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to post this answer in hope that that it will help someone else.
I spent a day trying to figure out how to solve this situation BUT the solution was very simple.

Instead of having two separate containers ONE FOR **php** and ONE FOR **nginx**, build a single container with **PHP**, **NGINX** and your **app**

Consider docker containers just as a single linux vm instance. A single vm can have multiple services running, so can a single docker container. Each service does not have to be in the different container.

Answer was easy if concepts are clear. Mine were not unfortunately.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok, so you grouped the two parts. That's the right thing to do. Yes, *docker* is simple to use, but it gets some time to understand its philosophy, mainly that it's not a VM provisioner such as *Vagrant*... A container is indeed not supposed to run only one process, but to serve only one purpose. In this specific case, *PHP-FPM* can be seen as a dependency of the web server.  
I wouldn't say that a container should be considered as a *single linux VM instance*, but as a *single application* (embedding all its dependencies including *Linux*).

Comment: I have two questions: how can I run two services in the same docker image? And what do you say to people who think the hard way with "one service = one image"?

Comment: You will have to build a Docker image to have multiple services. Consider docker as being a VM. So if you build Node.js and Golang in a single docker image it will run both. I hope it explains.